# Bulk importing raster data into GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite

I have more than 1000 world images in tiff format. I need to create the raster layers for those images in GeoServer 2.4-RC2 on Windows XP OS and set it as a backdrop in my web application. 
Is there any way for bulk importing in GeoServer? or 
any way to group those images into one raster store? or
Is there any opensource to do this job?

Please suggest me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to use the [image mosaic](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html) plugin, which will group the images into a single store. Also if the "tiffs" are not "geotiffs" you may want to consider converting them.

Comment: I would agree that this is the best method. However further to needing to convert from tiff to GeoTiff you will need to ensure that your images have been georeferenced. If there is not Georeferencing data as part of the image there is no way to automate adding this data. Each image will need to be loaded into a GIS application like QGIS and the bounds of the image set and the image saved in a format that supports GeoReferencing (like GeoTIFF)